# Tons of vulnerabilities are found on tcp/0 port using vulnerability scanners

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, ports, nessus, vulnerability-assessment

Performed credentialed vulnerability scan on Linux/Unix servers with Nessus and thousands of vulnerabilities are found on port **tcp/0**.

How could an IANA reserved port (tcp/0) handle traffic? Are those vulnerabilities true or false positives? How should we proceed with the remediation process of the vulnerabilities shown under port tcp/0?

Comment: Which scanner are you using? Is the number even remotely realistic? Take samples and check your system for the vulnerabilities. If your scanner shows so many and your system isn't 10 years old and completely unpatched, it's probably mostly false positives.

Comment: I am using Nessus Manger (7.0). In average, the count of vulnerability at tcp/0 of an red hat 6 server is nearly 1100-1200. I am not sure how much time they are left unpatched, but i can assume from the OS server version. I knew credential scan or agent based scan reduce the number of false positive and hence I performed the scan with credential or agent. I wonder, how it will be possible to filter the false positive from these large number of vulnerabilities from tcp/0!

Comment: Those are not necessarily false positives. I've updated my answer, see below.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> How could a IANA reserved port(tcp/0) handle traffic?

It *can*. Generally, TCP (or UDP) port 0 being in a reserved state doesn't mean it can't be used in practice. Though [the way Berkeley sockets are designed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1077305/2193305) it's not that easy to bind on port zero, [it's nevertheless possible](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2014/10/25/pretending-port-zero-is-a-normal-one/) to use it.

**However**, it's highly unlikely that this is *actually happening* in your case. You're just using the Nessus scanner which lists activities not closely related to a specific port under port 0/TCP or 0/UDP (see: [*"Vulnerabilities by Host"*](https://virginia.service-now.com/its/?id=itsweb_kb_article&sys_id=75e70054dbb553404f32fb671d9619d5)). This is simply an (inconvenient?) convention to display *port-less* warnings under port 0 -- ironically, to avoid confusion.

Note that those a) are not necessarily vulnerabilities, just warnings or suggestions (e.g. not adhering to [the best Microsoft practices](https://www.tenable.com/plugins/index.php?view=single&id=24786) while running a scanner); b) are not necessarily false positives. Try to ignore port zero itself, read the report carefully and act accordingly.

Comment: So, the mentioned port are actually the port Nessus Manager used for running the scan? If this is the case, Tenable should have mentioned it in their manual. 
By the way, In my case, many high/medium severity vulnerability is under tcp/0 (normally those vuln are real in my old servers i guess since they are not patched for long times). Since i installed nessus agents in those servers and performed scan using agents, those vuln might be listed under tcp/0.

Comment: "The second section is a list of the plugins, organized by the port used for the scan activities. Activities not closely related to a specific port are listed under port 0/TCP." This line is lifesaver from your given link.

Comment: @Shakir this is **NOT** the source port used for scanning. This is simply an (unconvenient) convention to display *port-less* warnings under port 0 -- ironically, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3):

> How could a IANA reserved port(tcp/0) handle traffic?

While the accepted answer explains how port 0 is still a real port, it may be helpful to understand how ports work in TCP. Below is a 32-bit-wide diagram of the a TCP packet, to scale. UDP is similar, although a lot simpler (after the ports, it has just a length field and a checksum field before the data).

```
0                   1                   2                   3
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|          Source Port          |       Destination Port        |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|                        Sequence Number                        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|                    Acknowledgment Number                      |
+-------+-----------+-+-+-+-+-+-+-------------------------------+
|  Data |           |U|A|P|R|S|F|                               |
| Offset| Reserved  |R|C|S|S|Y|I|            Window             |
|       |           |G|K|H|T|N|N|                               |
+-------+-----------+-+-+-+-+-+-+-------------------------------+
|           Checksum            |         Urgent Pointer        |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|                    Options                    |    Padding    |
+-----------------------------------------------+---------------+
|                                                               |
/                   ... Data (optional) ...                     /
|                                                               |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see, the source port and destination port fields are both 16 bits wide. This means it can represent 65536 different possible states, from 0 to 65535. This is incidentally why there are no negative ports, as the value is treated as unsigned. The only thing stopping any of the ports from being all null bytes (representing port 0) is an IANA standard saying not to do that. It is perfectly possible for a packet to be sent out with any of the ports set to 0. The purpose of keeping port 0 reserved is to allow "just give me any port" to be represented by a 16-bit integer. When an attempt is made to bind to TCP/0, rather than listening for packets with the destination port set to all zeros, the system is supposed to bind to any available port.